# Rely on order of form elements on the server PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

With a HTML form, can I rely on the ordering of the fields in HTML be the same as the data beingsent to the server?

For example if I have 2 inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="one"/>
<input type="text" class="aaa" name="two[]"/>
<input type="text" class="bbb" name="two[]"/>
```

When parsing the data on the server side and looping over input named 'two', can I rely on the fact that input.aaa will be first in the loop.

I am using php, but the same question applies to all major backend languages receiving form (post) data.

Comment: so if I was needing to make a form that is sortable, I would have to use javascript to send a position number to the server?

Comment: That would be the best way to do it as it would ensure you know the position of every value as it is fully in your control.  Plus you have to remember that users can mess with your HTML. Never trust them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You can manipulate the order by manually setting the index in the input's name:

```
<input type="text" class="aaa" name="two[0]"/>
<input type="text" class="bbb" name="two[1]"/>
```